# Is it possible to call a method on the rootViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to observe the global property selectedTagIDs and run a method on the rootViewController. Is this possible? How would I get a reference to the rootViewController?

```
import UIKit

class Global {
  static var sharedInstance = Global()
  var tags = [Tag]()
  var selectedTagIDs = [Int]() {
    didSet {
      // get error `use of unresolved identifier appDelegate`
      let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! MainViewController
      viewController.filterItems()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this **if** your `rootViewController` is of the type of class you are expecting that can respond to that method call. Conditionally check for the `rootViewController as? MainViewController`.

The reason you are getting that error is because you have not defined what `appDelegate` is in your code. To fix this we can use optional chaining to unwrap the `UIApplication` singleton's delegate and assign it as the value of `appDelegate`. And from there we can get the window and thus the `rootViewController`. As we unwrap the `viewController` we conditionally check if it is of type `MainViewController` and if so, tell it to `filterItems()`.

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? MainViewController {
    viewController.filterItems()
}
```